# Fully faithful functors on set-theoretic level

Tags: category-theory

Do there exist two small categories $C$, $D$ such that there is a fully faithful functor $C\rightarrow D$ and a functor injective (surjective, bijective) on objects $C\rightarrow D$ but no fully faithful functor injective (surjective, bijective) on objects $C\rightarrow D$? I just started thinking about this in relation to maps of Kaehler manifolds (it might happen that there is a symplectomorphism, a biholomorphism but no isomorphism of Kaehler manifolds).

Comment: There exist two categories with a fully faithful functor and a injective on objects funcor, but no fully faithful injective on objects functor. You can construct small toy examples by explicitly giving objects and morphism (I could do with both categories having $3$ objects, $C$ having 4 morphisms, and $D$ having $3$ morphisms). Basically the idea is that the fully faithful functor has to collapse two objects (ow it would be injective on functors), and the injective on objects functor has to collapse two morphisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, consider the disjoint union of two copies of a monoid $M$ mapping to $M\sqcup *$, where $*$ is the terminal category. Then the functor that collapses both copies of $M$ is fully faithful, but any injective-on-objects or surjective-on-objects functor must have $*$ in its image, so that it's not fully faithful.